# Need to embed one android project into another android project

Tags: android

I have two android projects with me. I need to add the first project as a library to the other project.

Now, when I am trying to open the activity of library project from the other application on a button click, i am getting Android.content.ActivityNotFoundException at run time.

Can anyone suggest some pointer on this.

Comment: Do you use android studio?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check that you added the new activity to the manifest.xml file
if you are Using **ADT(Android Developer Tool).**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the concern. This issue is resolved for me. Sorry for the late reply. I have created the second application as library project, which is included in first android project.

The point, which fixed the issue is:  add the contents of the manifest.xml  of library project in main project and the reference provided is the full path for the activity(including package name).